# My rigid body models are dropping through the floor

Tags: java, libgdx

My rigid body models are dropping through the floor. I am experimenting with Libgdx. When models fall on the ground created from a box they stop moving, but when I replace the ground with a model created from blender the objects fall through. I am trying to build a road track. Here is the code and other examples I tried I keep getting objects that fall through the modeled ground. I'm using blender for the modelling.

```
     public BulletSample(ThrustCopter thrustCopter) {
    super(thrustCopter);
    // Create ModelBatch that will render all models using a camera
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch(new DefaultShaderProvider());

    // Create a camera and point it to our model
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(10f, 10f, 12f);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    camera.near = 0.1f;
    camera.far = 300f;
    camera.update();

    // Create the generic camera input controller to make the app interactive
    cameraController = new CameraInputController(camera);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(cameraController);

    // Set up environment with simple lighting
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    // environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.Fog, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -0.8f, 0.3f, -1f));
    shadowLight = new DirectionalShadowLight(1024, 1024, 60, 60, 1f, 300);
    shadowLight.set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -.8f, -.2f);
    environment.add(shadowLight);
    environment.shadowMap = shadowLight;
    shadowBatch = new ModelBatch(new DepthShaderProvider());

    Bullet.init();

    collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
    broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
    solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
    world = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);
    world.setGravity(new Vector3(0, -9.81f, 1f));

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
/*  Model ground = modelBuilder.createBox(40f, 2f, 40f,
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
            Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
    groundInstance=new ModelInstance(ground);

    btCollisionShape groundshape = new btBoxShape(new Vector3(20, 1f, 20));
    shapes.add(groundshape);
    btRigidBody body = new btRigidBody(0,null,groundshape);
    bodies.add(body);
    world.addRigidBody(body); */
// testing rigid body ground with model from blender
    game.manager.load("gameAssets/roadtest1.g3db", Model.class);
    game.manager.finishLoading();

    Model roadmodel = game.manager.get("gameAssets/roadtest1.g3db", Model.class);
     roadInstance = new ModelInstance(roadmodel);
    //instances.add(road);
    btCollisionShape roadshape = createConvexHullShape(roadmodel, true);
    shapes.add(roadshape);
    btRigidBody body = new btRigidBody(0, null, roadshape);
    world.addRigidBody(body);

    Vector3 position=new Vector3();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Model box = modelBuilder.createBox(1f, 1f, 1f, 
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.BLUE)),
                Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
        ModelInstance boxInstance=new ModelInstance(box);
        instances.add(boxInstance);
        models.add(box);
        if(i<5){
            position.set(-1, i+1, 0);
        }else{
            position.set(1, i-4, 0);
        }
        boxInstance.transform.setToTranslation(position);

        btDefaultMotionState motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(boxInstance.transform);
        motionState.setWorldTransform(boxInstance.transform.trn(0, 0, 0));
        motionStates.add(motionState);
        btCollisionShape boxshape = new btBoxShape(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        shapes.add(boxshape);
        btRigidBody boxbody = new btRigidBody(1, motionState, boxshape);
        bodies.add(boxbody);
        world.addRigidBody(boxbody);
    }


    //Loading model
    game.manager.load("planeanim1.g3db", Model.class);
    game.manager.finishLoading();

    Model model = game.manager.get("planeanim1.g3db", Model.class);
    ModelInstance plane = new ModelInstance(model);
    instances.add(plane);

    plane.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Y, 180);
    plane.transform.trn(0, 7, 10);

    btDefaultMotionState motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(plane.transform);
    motionState.setWorldTransform(plane.transform.trn(0, 0, 0));
//  motionState.setWorldTransform(plane.transform.rotate(0, 0, .5f,45));
    motionStates.add(motionState);
    btCollisionShape planeshape = createConvexHullShape(model,true);
    shapes.add(planeshape);
    btRigidBody planebody = new btRigidBody(5, motionState, planeshape);
    bodies.add(planebody);
    world.addRigidBody(planebody);
    planebody.userData="plane";
    planebody.applyCentralImpulse(new Vector3(0,0,-65));

    // You use an AnimationController to control animations.  Each control is tied to the model instance
    controller = new AnimationController(plane);  
    // Pick the current animation by name
    controller.setAnimation("Scene",-1);

    contactListener = new MyContactListener();
}
public static btConvexHullShape createConvexHullShape (final Model model, boolean optimize) {
    final Mesh mesh = model.meshes.get(0);
    final btConvexHullShape shape = new btConvexHullShape(mesh.getVerticesBuffer(), mesh.getNumVertices(), mesh.getVertexSize());
    if (!optimize) return shape;
    // now optimize the shape
    final btShapeHull hull = new btShapeHull(shape);
    hull.buildHull(shape.getMargin());
    final btConvexHullShape result = new btConvexHullShape(hull);
    // delete the temporary shape
    shape.dispose();
    hull.dispose();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    groundInstance.model.dispose();
    instances.clear();
    modelBatch.dispose();
    for (Model model : models)
        model.dispose();
    for (btRigidBody body : bodies) {
        body.dispose();
    }
    for (btMotionState motion : motionStates)
        motion.dispose();
    for (btCollisionShape shape : shapes)
        shape.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    collisionConfiguration.dispose();
    dispatcher.dispose();
    broadphase.dispose();
    solver.dispose();
    contactListener.dispose();
    shadowBatch.dispose();
    shadowLight.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 1);

    if(started){
    world.stepSimulation(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < motionStates.size; i++) {
        motionStates.get(i).getWorldTransform(instances.get(i).transform);
    }
    }else{
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            started=true;
            System.out.println(instances.size);
            if(Gdx.input.justTouched())instances.get(10).transform.rotate(0,0.2f,0,25);
        }
    }

    // Respond to user events and update the camera
    cameraController.update();
    controller.update(delta);

    shadowLight.begin(Vector3.Zero, camera.direction);
    shadowBatch.begin(shadowLight.getCamera());
    shadowBatch.render(instances);

    shadowBatch.end();
    shadowLight.end();

    // Draw all model instances using the camera
    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    //modelBatch.render(groundInstance, environment);
    modelBatch.render(roadInstance, environment);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();

    super.render(delta);
}
```

Comment: Try looking for bugs using debug mode like explained here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75327/125185

Comment: Your createConvexHullShape method assumes untransformed meshes. Since you're using blender, it is very likely that the model parts are transformed. This probably causes the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the response but how do I rectify this, is it from the code or from the blender file?

Comment: If you really need a convex hull then you should make sure that your model is suitable for that. However, looking at your code you probably shouldn't be using a convex hull to begin with. Using `Bullet.obtainStaticNodeShape` might be better suited. However in that case your model still can't have scaling and too large or too small triangles, so you probably have to check that. And even then, chances are it isn't suitable. The variable is named "road", if your intention is to have a car or character travel smoothly on this shape, then you can better use primitive shapes like boxes.